# VBA For Loop with Dates - argument not optional error

Tags: excel, vba

Running the code below works in one workbook but not another and I cannot work out why! The error line is the For d = DateSerial....

[image: here is the error I get]

```
For Each dateKey In Json
       For d = DateSerial(Year(dateKey("dateFrom")), Month(dateKey("dateFrom")), Day(dateKey("dateFrom"))) To DateSerial(Year(dateKey("dateTo")), Month(dateKey("dateTo")), Day(dateKey("dateTo")))
        'Petrol
        ws.Cells(i, 1) = d
        ws.Cells(i, 2) = dateKey("petrol_1400")
        ws.Cells(i, 3) = dateKey("petrol_2000")
        ws.Cells(i, 4) = dateKey("petrol_9999")

        'Diesel
        ws.Cells(i, 6) = d
        ws.Cells(i, 7) = dateKey("diesel_1600")
        ws.Cells(i, 8) = dateKey("diesel_2000")
        ws.Cells(i, 9) = dateKey("diesel_9999")

        'LPG
        ws.Cells(i, 11) = d
        ws.Cells(i, 12) = dateKey("lpg_1400")
        ws.Cells(i, 13) = dateKey("lpg_2000")
        ws.Cells(i, 14) = dateKey("lpg_9999")

        i = i + 1
    Next d
                 
skipDate:
    Next
```

Here are the referenced I use for this file:

[image: Here is the reference I use in this workbook]

This is the reference from the working workbook

[image: This is the reference from the working workbook]

The working workbook is where the module was written - the workbook that it is not working in has been built to check for code updates when it opens and then pull in any new modules/updated modules and run any code predefined to run. Does anyone have any ideas why I get this error and why it is in a simple for loop?

Comment: Can you explain why you're using `DateSerial`?

Comment: I make an api request to web app that returns values (of which some are dates). I then need to take those dates and loop between the dates for each day. The dates return as JSON from the api and are I believe string type so need to become dates for the loop

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `CDate`? Or `DateValue`?

Comment: changed the line to `For d = CDate(dateKey("dateFrom")) To CDate(dateKey("dateTo")) ` but still get the same error

Comment: It might help to provide a sample value for `Json`.

Comment: The JSON is the same as in the other working workbook! I cant work out what there would be an Argument not optional error on a For loop even now it's `For d = CDate(dateKey("dateFrom")) To CDate(dateKey("dateTo"))` especially when it works exactly the same in another workbook

Comment: Unfortunately without a sample value, I'm not sure this is a [reprex] for anyone else to figure it out either

Comment: I've just got it - `Dim d as Date` and the error has gone! No option explicit defined so not sure why that has caused a problem in this workbook and not another but thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Side note, it seems you're actually converting `dateKey("dateFrom")` and `dateKey("dateTo")` into `Date` values 4 times each: thrice implicitly via `Year`, `Month`, and `Day` function calls (each performing a conversion into a `Date` to extract the part), and then once explicitly with `DateSerial` taking the three parts to build a `Date` value. If merely declaring `d As Date` fixed your issue, then consider using `CDate(dateKey("dateFrom"))` and `CDate(dateKey("dateTo"))` to only convert each date once instead.

Answer (score 0):

Define d as a Date type
`dim d as date`
this solved the problem

Comment: That code compiled fine for me just with `Dim d` (so as variant) .  Likely you have a sub or function somewhere in your project named `d` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams the local variable would have taken precedence over anything with the same name declared in a wider scope though.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Agreed, *as long as it had been declared at all*.   It's not clear whether OP declared it as variant and swapped to Date or just didn't declare it.  The latter seems to more likely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are potentially getting a null value back from the JSON which is causing this error. If you run this code you'll get the same error:

```
a = DateSerial(2022, 1, 27)
Debug.Print (a)
a = DateSerial()
Debug.Print (a)
```

If so you will need to code in an If dateKey = null